# Count with GroupBY does not count the actual number of records, shows as 1 only

Tags: sql, count, ssms

I have this simple sample that I'm working with. I have 2 records that are the same, and I'm just trying to roll these two records up so that it shows 2 as count since X and Y are exact

```
WITH test AS (
    SELECT '11' AS X, 'BYE'AS y
    UNION
    SELECT '11' AS X, 'BYE' AS Y
)

SELECT x, y, COUNT(x)
FROM test
GROUP BY x,y
```

Comment: Have you seem your CTE result?http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/121201

Comment: `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`

Comment: @spender dummy is me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the `COUNT` nor the `GROUP BY` and everything to do with your `UNION`. Your CTE (`test`) only provides one row as a `UNION` query returns **distinct** rows and you only have one distinct row. Use `UNION ALL`:

```sql
WITH test AS (
    SELECT '11' AS X, 'BYE'AS y
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '11' AS X, 'BYE' AS Y
)
SELECT x, y, COUNT(x)
FROM test
GROUP BY x,y;
```

Better yet, don't use that old style and use a `VALUES` table construct:

```sql
WITH test AS(
    SELECT x,y
    FROM (VALUES(11,'BYE'),
                (11,'BYE'))V(x,y))
SELECT x, y, COUNT(x)
FROM test
GROUP BY x,y;
```